# SQL Update statement with MEL expression - Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a `SQL UPDATE` statement, to update a particular record to the Database within a mule flow. I am having problems with including MEL expression within the statement and the SQL is not getting executed in my flow.

I am trying the next command:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET STATUS=#[flowVars['TxnStatus']] WHERE REF_NUM=#[flowVars['ReferenceNumber']]
```

where `TxnStatus` and `ReferenceNumber` are flow variables in my mule Flow. It looks seemingly simple, but the record is not updated.

When I try a similar `SELECT` statement with MEL expressions it does retrieve the value for me. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,

Added config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="MuleDB_DataSource" user="${MuleDB_User}" password="${MuleDB_Password}" url="${MuleDB_URL}" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MuleDB_DataSource" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="10000" doc:name="Database" transactionPerMessage="false">
    </jdbc-ee:connector>
    <flow name="ExceptionFlowFlow1" doc:name="ExceptionFlowFlow1">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="Exception" doc:name="VM"/>
        <set-variable variableName="ExceptionPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="ExceptionPayload"/>
        <set-variable variableName="TxnStatus" value="Failure" doc:name="Variable"/>        
        <logger message="#[variable:TxnStatus]" level="INFO" category="Status" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="Update_Status" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Update_Status">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="Update_Status" value="UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET STATUS=#[flowVars['TxnStatus'] WHERE PAYMENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER=#[flowVars['TxnReference']"/>
         </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="#[exception]" level="INFO" category="ExceptionFlow failed with the exception --" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: 1) look for error messages in the Mule console 2) turn on logging for your database and look at the incoming SQL statement.

Comment: @AntonKupias - Thanks for your reply. I do not have access to the database logs, and on the mule console, I am not seeing any error message.

Comment: Try to log the statement & vars with logger, as well as the class names for the vars. JDBC conversions between numbers and strings can be an issues as well if you set vars with a different data type than the db expects. Var classes/values and db field types are the minimum information to get started with reproducing the problem if you have no error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues when  trying to use a flow variable as an SQL input value. Try replacing `#[flowVars['varName']]` with `#[variable:varName]` like so:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET STATUS=#[variable:TxnStatus] WHERE REF_NUM=#[variable:ReferenceNumber]
```

This has worked for me. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry. :( This is not working for me... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you amend your question to share your config file? Perhaps there is an error elsewhere.

Comment: @jvas I believe your error is down to your SQL statement: `UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET STATUS=#[flowVars['TxnStatus'] WHERE PAYMENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER=#[flowVars['TxnReference']` - you're referring to a variable `TxnReference` that hasn't been set anywhere in the config file you've provided - therefore nothing will be updated as the `WHERE` clause in your statement won't point to anything

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention that. It is a variable from the incoming mule message at the VM endpoint

Comment: Try logging it immediately after the `vm` endpoint to see if it's still in the invocation scope: `<logger level="INFO" message="#[variable:TxnReference]"/>`, or alternatively try `<logger level="INFO/>` to see all of the message properties - let me know what you get

Comment: I am able to view the variable using a logger. I have resolved the issue for now, please see my comment below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can see difference between value you used in query key and command given by you above

value="UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET STATUS=`#[flowVars['TxnStatus']` WHERE PAYMENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER=`#[flowVars['TxnReference']`"/>

Both are missing end `]` in query value. Correct it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE audit_detail
SET
  status = '3'
WHERE
  request_id = #[flowVars['ses_request_id']
AND
  message_id = #[flowVars['ses_message_id']
```